# Despoletar uma ação quando determinada hash é encontrada no URL

Tags: jquery, url, hash

A ideia é iniciar uma animação quando determinada hash é encontrada no URL.

**Exemplo**

Pegando no exemplo de uma página cuja navegação funciona por hash:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#john">John</a></li>
    <li><a href="#doe">Doe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Jane">Jane</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section id="john">Super BuBu</section>
<section id="doe">Super Saiyan</section>
<section id="jane">Jane Porter</section>
```

O utilizador clica no menu e a página faz a rolagem para o `id` em questão.
A ideia é despoletar uma ação quando por exemplo se acesso ao `#doe` que poderia ser realizado através do evento de clique no link com o `href` igual a `#doe`.

## Problema

Se o utilizador aceder diretamente à página através de um URL que já contém a hash para o direcionar para a secção correta, a ação previamente associada ao clique no elemento referido não é despoletada.

```
http://www.meusite.com/bananas.php#doe
```

## Pergunta

Como despoletar uma ação quando no URL do navegador é encontrada determinada hash?

Comment: Despoletar = disparar (acho) :)

Comment: @bigown Pois, [não sei](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=959) ;) Mas "disparar" ou "desencadear" também ficam bem! Apesar de correcto, pode-se alterar para fazer mais sentido às massas!

Comment: Hahaha, desculpe, mas "despoletar" soa MUITO engraçado no Brasil! Ah, e engraçado no Brasil quer dizer "divertido".

Comment: @bfavaretto Estou sempre a aprender :) Qual a palavra mais adequada para o que quis dizer que utilizariam ai?

Comment: Acho que "disparar", como sugeriu o bigown. E fico feliz de aprender essa nova palavra "despoletar", passarei a usá-la! Veremos se alguém irá me entender :)

Comment: Pensando em espoleta, faz todo o sentido.

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada na biblioteca [sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/). Parece promisora, mas como venho enrolando para aprendê-la faz tempo, ainda não tenho conhecimento suficiente para postar algo mais concreto como resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o problema é "o que fazer quando a página já abre com a hash presente", sugiro tornar mais genérico o método que trataria do clique, e invocá-lo logo após a página ser carregada:

```javascript
$(function() {

    var acoes = {
        "#hash1": function() { ... },
        "#hash2": function() { ... },
        ...
    };

    function executarAcao() {
        if ( window.location.hash && acoes[window.location.hash] )
            acoes[window.location.hash]();
    }

    $("a").filter(function() {
        return ($(this).attr("href") || "").indexOf("#") == 0;
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        executarAcao();
    });

    ...

    // No final do seu script
    executarAcao();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode monitorar o evento `hashchange`:

```js
window.onhashchange = function() {
    alert(window.location.hash);
};
```

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CDfzJ/)

Dentro da função você pode verificar o hash e atuar de acordo.

**Detalhes:**
Se não me engano, entre Firefox e Chrome, um dos dois despoleta (hehe) o evento `hashchange` automaticamente quando a página carrega, e no outro o evento precisa ser disparado manualmente. E o IE só suporta esse evento a partir da versão 8, e também não dispara o evento quando a página carrega.

Então é recomendável chamar `window.onhashchange()` assim que o DOM carregar, para obter o efeito que você deseja.

Comment: O `onhashchange` ocorre antes ou depois da "ação padrão" do clique? (i.e. quando esse método for executado, a tela já terá rolado?) Quando o OP diz "animação", a primeira coisa que me vem à cabeça é uma animação de scroll - o que exigiria que o `evt.preventDefault()` fosse chamado no handler do clique. E isso poderia **impedir** a hash de mudar, não?

Comment: Tem razão, se a idéia é previnir o rolamento automático é preciso usar o evento `click` como na sua solução, o `hashchange` não serve (ele ocorre *depois* do clique).

Comment: Fica o +1 pela resolução do problema, mas a resposta do @mgibsonbr vale pela solução global e integrada!